# Mapbox-gl and angular2

Tags: angular, mapbox-gl

i'm trying to integrate mapbox-gl to angular2 application. But after making the service app doesn't work.

Service

```
    import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { Map } from 'mapbox-gl';

@Injectable()
export class MapService {
    map: Map;
    baseMaps: any;

    constructor() {

        (mapboxgl as any).accessToken = 'my_acces_token(in original code included';)

    }

}
```

Module

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import {MapService} from './services/mapService/mapBox.service'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ],
  providers: [MapService]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

After starting the app this is error i get

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

and

```
ZoneAwareError
```

mabpox-gl was installed with these commands

```
npm install mapbox-gl --save

and 

npm install @types/mapbox-gl --save
```

Comment: Check your console. Is your url correct?

Answer (score 0):

Check your systemjs.config.js file. Probably you aren't set the path node_modules package.

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    map: {
      'mapbox-gl': '[Your node_module folder]/mapbox-gl/dist',
       [....]
       },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      'mapbox-gl': {
        main: './mapbox-gl.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      [....]
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstable, check if the @types library of mapboxgl support the mapbox-gl library version that you install.

Then, in service, declare the map like map: mapboxgl.Map;

and in your component declare the map like

```
this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            center: GlobalVariables.defaultCoord,
            maxZoom: GlobalVariables.defMaxZoom,
            minZoom: GlobalVariables.defMinZoom,
            zoom: GlobalVariables.defZoom,
            style: GlobalVariables.mapboxDark
        });
```

Finally, go to tsconfig.json, in the "compilerOptions" field, and check if you set the types property with the mapboxgl types. For example:

```
"compilerOptions": {
"moduleResolution": "node",
"target": "es5",
"sourceMap": true,
"experimentalDecorators": true,
"emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
"skipDefaultLibCheck": true,
"lib": [ "es5", "es6", "dom" ],
"types": [ "node", "geojson", "mapbox-gl" ]
```

}

I hope that this helps.
Regards.